# getting the quantity of products for the user - MongoDB, Angular, Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How to get the username from the `users` scheme and the number of its`products` products

**products :**

```
{
 _id : ObjectId(5ab548d8bea65e21c413766f),
 userid: 5ab425c6f5bff145304092f7,
 product_name: "aaa",
 __v:0
},{
 _id: ObjectId(5ab7daa92ade533790268f48),
 userid: 5ab655bbb94733156c438112,
 product_name: "bbb",
 __v:0
},{
 _id: ObjectId(5aba43ef0a5c243330237bd5),
 userid: 5ab425c6f5bff145304092f7,
 product_name: "ccc",
 __v:0
}
```

**users :**

```
{
 _id: ObjectId(5ab425c6f5bff145304092f7),
 username:"cccc",
 email:"cccc@gmail.com",
 __v:0
},{
 _id:ObjectId(5ab655bbb94733156c438112),
 username:"rrrr",
 email:"rrrr",
 __v:0
}
```

I would like the result to be as follows:

```
    [ { _id: { username: 'rrrr' } , count: 1},
      { _id: { username: 'cccc' } , count: 2} ]
```

For now, I started from this:

```
products.aggregate([

  {$lookup:{
    from: "users",
    localField: "ObjectId(userid)",
    foreignField: "ObjectId(_id)",
    as: "users"
  }},
  {"$group" : {_id:{userid:"$userid" }, count:{$sum:1} } }

  ], function(err, result) {
      console.log(result);
      if(err){ res.status(400).json({ success: false, message:'Error processing request '+ err }); }
          res.status(201).json({
            success: true,
            data: result
      });  
    }
  );
```

The script returns the following values:

```
[ { _id: { userid: '5ab655bbb94733156c438112' }, count: 1 },
  { _id: { userid: '5ab425c6f5bff145304092f7' }, count: 2 } ]
```

Field **userid** agrees, but I would like you to have the **username** attribute here. 
How to correct the script?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `$last` to get the grouped user `single data` and you can display that.

```
products.aggregate([

  {$lookup:{
    from: "users",
    localField: "ObjectId(userid)",
    foreignField: "ObjectId(_id)",
    as: "users"
  }},

{ "$group" :
  {
    _id: { userid: "$userid" },
    usrname: { $last: "$users.username" } ,
    count: { $sum: 1 }
  }
},

  ], function(err, result) {

      if(err){ res.status(400).json({ success: false, message:'Error processing request '+ err }); }
          res.status(201).json({
            success: true,
            data: result
      });  
    }
  );
}
```

[You can find the documentation here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/)

Comment: result your code : `[ { _id: { userid: '5ab655bbb94733156c438112' },
    username: null,
    count: 1 },
  { _id: { userid: '5ab425c6f5bff145304092f7' },
    username: null,
    count: 2 } ]`

Comment: I update: `username: { $last: "$users.username"  },` returns `[ { _id: { userid: '5ab655bbb94733156c438112' },
    username: [],
    count: 1 },
  { _id: { userid: '5ab425c6f5bff145304092f7' },
    username: [],
    count: 2 } ]`

Comment: changed `username` to your field name?

Comment: I think users is not an array so use `username: $users.username`

Comment: update: ` {
    "$group" :
    {
        _id:{userid:"$userid" },
          username: "$users.username"  ,
        count:{$sum:1}
    }
  }` returns: `undefined
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:494:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:501:3)

Comment: in my `users` collection I have a `username` field

Comment: what happens if you give,  `username: $users,`

Comment: works: `db.products.aggregate([
{$lookup:{
    from: "users",
    localField: "ObjectId(userid)",
    foreignField: "ObjectId(_id)",
    as: "users"
  }},
  { "$group" :
    { _id:{userid:"$userid" },
        name: { $last: "$users.username"  },
        count:{$sum:1}
    }
}]`

Comment: returns : `[ { _id: { userid: '5ab655bbb94733156c438112' },
    name: [ 'cccc', 'rrrr' ],
    count: 1 },
  { _id: { userid: '5ab425c6f5bff145304092f7' },
    name: [ 'cccc', 'rrrr' ],
    count: 2 } ]` but how to display it in Angular. This not work:
`<tr *ngFor="let product of products_users; let productIndex = index">
<td><input   value="{{product.name[productIndex]}}" [(ngModel)]="product._id.name[productIndex]" /></td>`

Comment: your code: `db.products.aggregate([{$lookup:{ from: "users", localField: "ObjectId(userid)", foreignField: "ObjectId(_id)", as: "users" }},{ "$group" : {_id:{userid:"$userid" }, count:{$sum:1}}}, {$project: { "_id" : 0, username: "$users.0.username", "count" :  1 }}], function(err, result) { console.log(result); if(err){ res.status(400).json({ success: false, message:'Error processing request '+ err });} res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: result }); });`

Comment: returns : `[ { count: 1 }, { count: 2 } ]`

Comment: it's almost working now:  `db.products.aggregate([ {$lookup:{ from: "users", localField: "ObjectId(userid)", foreignField: "ObjectId(_id)", as: "users" }},{ "$group" : { _id: { userid: "$userid" }, name: { $last: "$users.username" }, count: { $sum: 1 }}}]`

Comment: returns: `[ { _id: { userid: '5ab655bbb94733156c438112' },  name: ['cccc', 'rrrr'], count: 1 }, { _id: { userid: '5ab425c6f5bff145304092f7' },  name: ['cccc', 'rrrr'], count: 3 } ]` the values of the of the array `name` are not assigned to the `userid`. if the value of 'cccc'is the first element in the array, it should be `{ _id: { userid: '5ab425c6f5bff145304092f7' }`,  displayed in JSON as the first record

Answer (score 0):

**solution**

```
products.aggregate([

  {$lookup:{
    from: "users",
    localField: "ObjectId(userid)",
    foreignField: "ObjectId(_id)",
    as: "users"
  }},

{ "$group" :
  {
    _id: { userid: "$userid" },
    name: { $last: "$users.username" } ,
    count: { $sum: 1 }
  }
}, {$sort: {"_id.userid":  1}}

  ], function(err, result) {

      if(err){ res.status(400).json({ success: false, message:'Error processing request '+ err }); }
          res.status(201).json({
            success: true,
            data: result
      });  
    }
  );
}
```